# Abstract class dependency injection with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, abstract-class, castle-windsor

Castle Windsor is used as IoC-container.
There is `IPipeline` interface. It is implemented by base class: `PipelineBase : IPipeline`. In turn it is inherited by two classes: `FishPipeline : PipelineBase` and `OctopusPipeline : PipelineBase`.

There is two customer classes, upper classes must be injected into:

First class `LargeAquarium` needs both `FishPipeline` and `OctopusPipeline`. And second `TinyAquarium` needs only `FishPipeline`.

How can I solve it? Is there a need to add `IFishPipeline` and `IOctopusPipeline` interfaces?

Comment: You should add how you got the solution as an answer rather as part of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as long as injected objects need to expose something that is not part of `IPipeline`.

Comment: @ValeO What sample do you want? :D It's just that if you need injected objects as `IPipeline` to access more members than it provides itself, you need to make an `IPipelineExtended` (the name is up to you) and provide more members to be implemented by classes, and then configure this interface as component instead of `IPipeline`.

Comment: @ValeO Maybe you felt that my answer was too short, but sometimes short answers are better! I'm glad you got the idea. It's just about using regular interfaces as you do in any C# code.

Answer (score 1):

With the adoption of Matías's answer I was able to do it this way:

With given that both `FishPipeline` and `OctopusPipeline` has their own  additional members to access, that are not declared in `IPipeline`, anyway we need two new interfaces, `IOctopusPipeline` one of them. Then:

```
IOctopusPipeline: IPipeline

PipelineBase: IPipeline

OctopusPipeline: PipelineBase, IOctopusPipeline
```

Then inject:

```
 _container.Register(Component.For<IOctopusPipeline>().ImplementedBy<OctopusPipeline>());
```

Comment: But an interface can't implement a class! O_O

Comment: I'm talking about `IOctopusPipeline: PipelineBase, IOctopusPipeline`. I understand `PipelineBase` is a class. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Oops, mistake. It was `OctopusPipeline` before..)